# does appirater available for cocos2dx v3.0 for ios only in c++?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, appirater

I am new with cocos2dx v3.0 in c++. how can i add rate app reminder in IOS only? I followed that link  https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater but it is availble in objective-c only. Any suggestions please?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d-x do support calling objective-c code. Check AppController.mm file in ios folder of your cocos2d-x folder, its Objective-c. you can add appirater files in the same folder and can call Appirator method from within didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of AppController.mm